# How do I property dissect/disseminate a Dictionary with an Array?

Tags: swift, nsarray, nsdictionary

I'm trying to disseminate the response of a NSJSONSerialization:

```
let responseDict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &jsonError) as NSDictionary
```

So far, I have a good output which I want to dissect/disseminate:

```
(lldb) po responseDict
{
    photos =     {
        page = 1;
        pages = 1333;
        perpage = 100;
        photo =         (
                        {
                farm = 4;
                "height_m" = 243;
                "height_s" = 117;
                "height_sq" = 75;
                "height_t" = 49;
                id = 15148883617;
                isfamily = 0;
                isfriend = 0;
                ispublic = 1;
                owner = "48531100@N04";
                secret = fb6596ca90;
                server = 3926;
                title = "An Exceptional Roman Orichalcum Sestertius of Nero (54-68 C.E.), a Magnificent Depiction of the Temple of Janus on the Reverse";
                "url_m" = "https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3926/15148883617_fb6596ca90.jpg";
                "url_s" = "https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3926/15148883617_fb6596ca90_m.jpg";
                "url_sq" = "https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3926/15148883617_fb6596ca90_s.jpg";
                "url_t" = "https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3926/15148883617_fb6596ca90_t.jpg";
                "width_m" = 500;
                "width_s" = 240;
                "width_sq" = 75;
                "width_t" = 100;
            },
            ...
            ...
```

The problem is doing the dissemination. 
Here's the contents of "photos" key (rather ugly compared to the ObjC counterpart):

```
(lldb) po responseDict["photos"]
(instance_type = Builtin.RawPointer = 0x00007fce90ec74e0 -> 0x0000000105a910e0 (void *)0x0000000105a91220: __NSDictionaryM)
 {
  instance_type = 0x00007fce90ec74e0 -> 0x0000000105a910e0 (void *)0x0000000105a91220: __NSDictionaryM
}
```

This line produces a fatal (dynamic cast) crash:

```
let myPhotos = responseDict["photos"] as NSArray
```

Here's an ObjC equivalent (that works):

```
jsonDict[@"photos"][@"photo"];
```

Compare that to the following Swift equivalent that gives me an error (even though I had downcast it to NSDictionary):

```
(lldb) po responseDict["photos"]["photo"]
error: <EXPR>:1:1: error: 'AnyObject?' does not have a member named 'subscript'
responseDict["photos"]["photo"]
```

**Question:** How do I properly dissect a dictionary (or any collection) in Swift as I can in Objective-C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Objective-C code that works it appears that `responseDict["photos"]` is not an `NSArray`, it is `NSDictionary`. This should work:

```
let myPhotos = responseDict["photos"] as? NSDictionary
let photo = myPhotos!["photo"]
```

Comment: That's almost correct, a few typos...  Shall post answer.

Comment: @FrederickC.Lee You could also suggest an edit if you prefer by clicking [edit].

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get down to the individual dictionary:

```
let myPhotos = responseDict["photos"] as? NSDictionary
let photos = myPhotos!["photo"] as? NSArray
let myPhoto:AnyObject = photos![0]
println(myPhoto)
```

Here's the output:

```
{
    farm = 4;
    "height_m" = 500;
    "height_s" = 240;
    "height_sq" = 75;
    "height_t" = 100;
    id = 15150188169;
    isfamily = 0;
    isfriend = 0;
    ispublic = 1;
    owner = "87355413@N02";
    secret = e9cfed5225;
    server = 3905;
    title = "Miss 18mths wearing Music Box pinafore in grey denim (18-24mths). Trimmed with aqua/pink ric rac, and \"bow\" button.";
    "url_m" = "https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3905/15150188169_e9cfed5225.jpg";
    "url_s" = "https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3905/15150188169_e9cfed5225_m.jpg";
    "url_sq" = "https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3905/15150188169_e9cfed5225_s.jpg";
    "url_t" = "https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3905/15150188169_e9cfed5225_t.jpg";
    "width_m" = 375;
    "width_s" = 180;
    "width_sq" = 75;
    "width_t" = 75;
}
```

And to test it further:

```
let myPhoto = myPhotoInfo["url_m"] as String
```

Produces:

```
https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3920/15333895891_956d072454.jpg
```